# How did Susan make the connection to Oliver Queen being the Green Arrow but not the Hood/Arrow?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In season 5 episode 12 (Bratva), Susan's contact provides a dossier on Oliver's time in Russia, showing he was in the Bratva and additionally took up a guise similar to that of the Green Arrow. She then made the leap that he must be the Green Arrow.

Why did she also not make the leap that he was the Hood?

He was suspected of being the Hood on two occasions, and with the second time he was pretty much convicted for it until Roy Harper stepped in. So considering all the evidence that originally pointed to Oliver being the Hood, why does she not recall any of this?

Futher, the Hood precedes the Green Arrow, and Oliver's time in the Bratva precedes the Hood, so would that not have been a far more logical connection to make? Especially considering how the Hood showed up just after Oliver's return to Starling City.

Her current understanding of Oliver's general past seems to be as follows:

1. Shipwrecked on Lian Yu
2. Somehow ends up in Russia
3. Joins the Bratva
4. Takes up a guise similar to the Green Arrow and the Hood
5. Ends up back in Starling City from Lian Yu
6. Becomes CEO of Queen Consolidated for a while
7. Gets arrested for being the Hood. Totally innocent and is released.
8. Gets arrested a second time for being the Hood. Is released because of Roy Harper, now totally innocent again.
9. Green Arrow turns up. Oliver had absolutely nothing to do with that other guy, but now he's definitely the Green Arrow.

Comment: Even if she did it wouldn't be an important connection to make. At this point the Hood is obselete and the Green Arrow is the vigilante of the land. There is a decent chance that she put two and two together but even if she did, the Hood is officially dead and therefore his crimes are obselete. And what does she care if he was the Hood? The Hood doesn't matter anymore Green Arrow does.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like a logical connection to make, but the story that Roy Harper was the Hood/the Arrow was pushed *very* strongly at the time. Remember that both times Oliver was accused of being the Hood, the police *and the public* got proof that he wasn't: the first time, Diggle shows up in the outfit, and the second time, Roy confesses. Both of those were very high profile and public events, so they would likely be firmly embedded in the mind of a reporter.

The idea that the Green Arrow is a completely different person -- someone who is trying to be "the better, heroic" version of The Arrow, has been the narrative for a long time now.

To us, who already know they are the same person, it seems that it should be obvious. But here's what *Susan* thinks she knows to be true:

- The Hood was a mean, violent, aggressive mass-murder. The Green Arrow is a hero who doesn't kill.
- Roy Harper, not Oliver Queen, confessed to being The Hood/Arrow.
- The Arrow died in prison and hasn't been seen since. Oliver Queen is clearly not dead.
- The Green Arrow only appeared later, after the Arrow died, to take up his cause.

From her perspective, she's going to connect Oliver w/ the Green Arrow because that guy is still around and used a uniform a lot like Oliver's. The Hood is dead and gone, of course that's not Oliver. If she even thought about it, she probably assumed he was just another Bratva guy using the same gear as Oliver.

Comment: *"The Green Arrow is a hero who doesn't kill."* - **mostly!**